# How to express the $C_3$ Rotation symmetry in Graphene using sublattice basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry, graphene

In many articles, the $C_3$ Rotation matrix is expressed as $U=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}\sigma_z}$,where $\sigma$ is the pauli matrix in sublattice space, the symmetry of the tight binding hamiltonian is expressed as $UH(k)U^\dagger=H(C_3k)$, but I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

After thinking for a while, I think I understand this equation, since we expand the crystal momentum around one valley of the BZ of the graphene (K valley, for example), under the basis transformation:
\begin{equation}
c_{\vec{k},A}^\dagger=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_R e^{i(k+K)\cdot (R+r_a)}c_A^\dagger(R+r_A)
\end{equation}
where $r_A=(a,0)$, lattice vector $a_1,a_2$ ,reciprocal lattice vectors choosen as $b_1=(\frac{2\pi}{3a},\frac{2\sqrt{3}\pi}{3a}),b_2=(\frac{2\pi}{3a},-\frac{2\sqrt{3}\pi}{3a})$

Under $C_3$ rotation, the operator becomes:
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_R e^{i(k+K)\cdot (R+r_a)}c_A^\dagger(C_3R+r_A-a_2)\\
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_R e^{i[C_3(k+K)]\cdot [C_3(R+r_a)]}c_A^\dagger(C_3R+r_A-a_2)\\
=&e^{-i(b_1+b_2)\cdot r_A}\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_R e^{i(C_3k+K)\cdot (C_3R+r_A-a_2)}c_A^\dagger(C_3R+r_A-a_2)\\
=&e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}c_{C_3\vec{k},A}^\dagger
\end{align}
a similar phase factor $e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$ can be obtained when considering the case for sublattice B, so the transformation operator becomes $e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}\sigma_z}$.